# Exporting blinking lights from blender to Unreal Engine

Tags: animation, export, light, lighting

I was wondering how would I go about taking my animated mesh with blinking lights (Airplanes or old creepy lights) and export them to Unreal Engine? Ive never exported to UE so just wondering how its done? Would the animation be good enough or do I have to redo everything in UE?

Comment: Not a game engine expert myself, but that sounds like the kind of thing you would need to do in engine, not Blender